# How can I limit an existing Rails AR query by a certain time frame?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a dashboard(esque) view in a Rails app which is showing some data in similar ways but broken out into many time periods.

I have some code in my controller like so:

```
@issues_this_month = Issue.where('issues.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.in_time_zone.beginning_of_month, DateTime.now.in_time_zone.end_of_month)
```

and I also want to create a variables which shows issues this year and issues all time so I have this code:

```
@issues_this_year = Issue.where('issues.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.in_time_zone.beginning_of_year, DateTime.now.in_time_zone.end_of_year)
```

I am curious if someone can think of a good way of doing one query, and from that inferring the date ranges all while avoiding the extra queries. Should I pass the results to a helper method and do the  logic there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the model... you can define

```
def date
  self.created_at.to_date
end
```

then in the controller

```
start = Date.today.beginning_of_year
end = Date.today.end_of_year
@issues_this_year = Issue.where(create_at: start..end).group_by(&:date)
```

now you have a hash of [month_1, {issues that exist in month_1}, month_2, {issues that exist in month_2}, etc].  play with it in the console to find the proper keys... `@issues_this_year.keys`

Comment: I believe an edit needs to happen: '.group' instead of '.group_by'

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by - I've used it with group_by.  there is a group, but it's different, if I recall...

Comment: the `&` symbol is a bit of a shortcut.  It's the same as saying `.group_by(|x| x.date)`

Answer (score -1):

How about defining a method like

```
def self.in_timeframe(start_time=DateTime.now.in_time_zone.beginning_of_month,
                 end_time=DateTime.now.in_time_zone.end_of_month)
  Issue.where('issues.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_time, end_time)
end
```

You can now invoke this as follows:

```
Issue.in_timeframe # For issues in the month
Issue.in_timeframe(x,y) # For issues within x-y timeframe
```

If you want the data in a single query, you could do stuff like:

```
def self.in_timeframes(time_frames)
  data = {}
  times_frames.each do |time_frame|
    data[time_frame[:name]] = Issue.in_timeframe(time_frame[:srtart]. time_frame[:end])
  end
  data
end
```

You can invoke the above method using:

```
time_frames = [{:name=>"month"},
               {:name=>"x-y", :start=>x, :end=>y}]
Issue.in_timeframes(time_frames)
```

Comment: You can also use ActiveRecord Scopes for this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments

Comment: the point of my question was avoiding the extra queries, but I appreciate your effort!

Comment: Hey, I have modified the code to use a single-invoker Issue.in_timeframes that ill return a key-value pair. Key being the type of time-frame, value being the the issues in the time-frame. This  hash can be passed to the Helpers to render. Lemme know your thoughts

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but wouldn't this still perform more than one query? If I passed in a hash of two time frames it will still run an AR query for each k,v pair. I was thinking more a long the lines of altering the results of the result object to get what I wanted.

Comment: Oh. I have misread your query then. I thought, you wanted a single invoking. Now I understand, you need a single MySQL query. It would be  cumbersome I guess. You would be having to do lot of Ruby looping to achieve it after MySQL returns you the data, which will be expensive in terms of performance.